# How to get gulp watch till js file is saved in source

Tags: javascript, gulp-watch

I'm new to gulp and i'm loving it. Have a newbie problem and would like to get some advice. My gulp is set to watch on changes to js source files. When there are changes, it minifies the file and throws to a destination folder. However i notice that the moment i start typing on the source js, it tries to minify. I don't want this, i would like it to run only upon saving the file. I have tried a few plugins like gulp-changed, gulp-newer and also attempted this code, but nothing worked. Searched everywhere but after 2 good hours, decided to ask here. Some advice would be good. Thanks.

This is what i tried

```
/*-- minify js --*/
gulp.task('minifyjs', function(){
return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')  
    .pipe(changed('src/js/*.js')            
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(js_obfuscator())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/min'))
});
```

Comment: We will need to see your gulp watch task as well.  I don't think there is anything wrong with the code you presented.  However, I would assume your code editor has some sort of autosave feature that is saving automatically whenever you start making changes.  Probably nothing to do with gulp at all.

Comment: WOW!! that's it! I saw the autosave enabled in vs code. I turned it off and it works perfect. Thanks so much.